# Is it possible to start two Xorg X-Servers with intel graphics on same machine?

Tags: xorg, intel

Whenever I want to start a second X-Server (one is running on display :0, I started the second with `X :1`, as root, but as normal user it doesn't work either) it won't start. The relevant error message seems to be `(EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].` and `(EE) intel(0): Failed to claim DRM device.` (the `(EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied` is there also for the successfully running Xorg on display :0).

Does anyone know a way to start a second Xserver?

I am using intel driver, kernel-side it is i915 with modesetting.

The relevant Xorg.log is attached.

```
[  6646.990] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
[  6646.996] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  6646.998] Build Operating System: Linux 4.0.4-2-ARCH x86_64 
[  6647.004] Current Operating System: Linux felics-tablet 3.18.21-ck-bfs-tuxice-uksm-bfq-gccopt-phcintel #6 PREEMPT Tue Sep 15 20:07:15 CEST 2015 x86_64
[  6647.005] Kernel command line: root=/dev/sda5 ro kdb=off loglevel=9 pcie_aspm=force slub_debug=- vt.default_utf8=1 fbcon=font:VGA8x8 acpi_backlight=vendor intel_iommu=off vga=6 resume=/dev/sda9
[  6647.012] Build Date: 30 June 2015  09:00:12PM
[  6647.014]  
[  6647.016] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[  6647.021]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  6647.021] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  6647.032] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Thu Sep 17 11:41:35 2015
[  6647.035] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  6647.037] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  6647.038] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  6647.038] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  6647.038] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  6647.038] (**) |   |-->Monitor ""
[  6647.039] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[  6647.039] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[  6647.039] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  6647.039] (**) Option "AutoAddDevices" "true"
[  6647.039] (**) Automatically adding devices
[  6647.039] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  6647.039] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  6647.039] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/local/,
    /usr/share/fonts/misc/,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF/,
    /usr/share/fonts/Type1/,
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi/,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi/
[  6647.039] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  6647.039] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  6647.039] (II) Loader magic: 0x816d60
[  6647.039] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  6647.039]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  6647.039]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
[  6647.039]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.1
[  6647.039]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[  6647.042] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to get session: The name org.freedesktop.login1 was not provided by any .service files
[  6647.043] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  6647.043] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[  6647.480] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:2a42:17aa:20e4 rev 7, Mem @ 0xf2000000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00001800/8
[  6647.481] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:1) 8086:2a43:17aa:20e4 rev 7, Mem @ 0xf2400000/1048576
[  6647.481] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[  6647.481] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[  6647.481] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[  6647.481] (II) Module "dri" already built-in
[  6647.481] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  6647.482] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  6647.485] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6647.486]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  6647.486]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[  6647.486] (==) AIGLX enabled
[  6647.486] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[  6647.486] (II) Module "extmod" already built-in
[  6647.486] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[  6647.486] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[  6647.486] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  6647.486]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 2.99.917
[  6647.486]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  6647.486]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[  6647.486] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[  6647.487] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[  6647.487] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[  6647.487] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[  6647.487] (--) using VT number 14

[  6647.499] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20140905
[  6647.499] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled from 2.99.917-364-gb24e758
[  6647.500] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[  6649.679] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].
[  6649.679] (II) intel(0): [drm] Contents of '/sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/clients':
[  6649.679] (II) intel(0): [drm]              command   pid dev master a   uid      magic
[  6649.679] (II) intel(0): [drm]                 Xorg 16216   0   y    y  1001          0
[  6649.679] (II) intel(0): [drm]        fuzzy-windows 16243   0   n    y  1001         10
[  6649.679] (II) intel(0): [drm]                 Xorg 17590   0   n    y     0          0
[  6649.679] (EE) intel(0): Failed to claim DRM device.
[  6649.679] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[  6649.679] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[  6649.679] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  6649.679] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[  6649.679] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  6649.680] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
[  6649.680] (EE) 
[  6649.697] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: i did something like this long ago.  but it was 3 X servers.  i vaguely remember a few settings each needed.  i started them all from init scripts (so they started from root). and it was an older version.  i have no need to do it today (it was done as an easy means to switch limited video modes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... And the solution is the following:

The other X servers need to run with a different driver. `fbdev` works. Before starting the second server, edit the Xorg config file (or automate things by re-soft-linking config files and starting up X with one command) to use the fbdev video driver.